# Swift unexpectedly found nil after second try?

Tags: json, swift, fatal-error

Just learning how to work with JSON on Swift using some APIs from a gaming company. I have encountered an error in my code.

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Though on my first try in my app it works perfectly fine, this only occurs when I want to search for another name on my app.

Here's the code I have:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var data = NSMutableData()

    @IBOutlet weak var summonerName: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    func startConnection(){
        var text: String = summonerName.text
        let urlPath: String = "https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/\(text)?api_key=<key>"
        var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
        var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        var connection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)!
        connection.start()
    }

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!){
        self.data.appendData(data)
    }

    @IBAction func buttonAction(sender: UIButton) {
         startConnection()
    }

    func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!){
        var err: NSError?
        var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as! NSDictionary
        println(jsonResult)
    }
}
```

EDIT: I have added the if - else to my jsonResult to see if the text entered is Empty or not and also a print method to see if the text is inputted correctly. My problem still exists that on my first try everything works fine and I was able to extract the "summonerLevel" information I need, however, as soon as I type another name to search for the fatal error resumed. ALTHOUGH on my search text the name was correctly searched for.

Comment: Are you getting this error on fetching value from textfield: var text: String = summonerName.text ? or on self.data while accessing it.

Comment: Unwrap all optionals with if let a = a { /** do something */ } else { /** log error message here*/ } and you will see where problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the error is here:

```
let urlPath: String = "https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/\(text)?api_key=<key>"
var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
```

In `urlPath` you should probably replace `<key>` with some real api key. I tested that code in a playground, and `NSURL(string: urlPath)` returns `nil` - the forced unwrapping operator applied on it causes the exception.

I tried changing `<key>` with a random number, and it worked instead.

Comment: thanks for the reply Antonio! Yes I hid the api key because I only get certain amount of traffic in a given time frame with my unique api key so I just decided to hide it.

I am not too certain if I follow you correctly
I tried taking out the ! so to keep it an optional however xcode produced an error and asks me to include the ! as what my code is showing

Comment: Do you mean that you replaced the actual valid value with the `<key>` placeholder?

Comment: I have the actual api key inside my actual urlPath. The code works for me whenever I click on my button "connect" on my iphone simulation however, if i click again it will produce the "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"